# how to suppress the coverity warning "CHECKED_RETURN"

Tags: c, coverity

On following code

```
TRACE_SEND_SIG(pOutSig, sender((void *) &pSig),"IPOM_DHCP_IF_UNSUBSCRIBE_RSP");

send((void *) &pOutSig, sender((void *) &pSig));
```

Coverity emits error:

> Calling `send((void *)&pOutSig, sender((void *)&pSig))` without
>   checking return value. This library function may fail and return an
>   error code.

In above code context it is intentional to not check the return value of `send`. How can I suppress this error.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to avoid the warning.

Comment: Just as it says, do not ignore return code: res = send((void *) &pOutSig, sender((void *) &pSig));

Comment: Please do not deface your posts.

Comment: Coverity works at AST (Abstract syntax tree) level and there is no way of avoiding this error. Even by the trick mentioned in the other answer. You can try to suppress it in the coverity report by code annotation /* coverity[check_return] */ in a line before `send` call. Note: suppressing in coverity only means marking an error as intentional. It will still show up in the issues list, but with status dismissed (intentional).

Answer (score 5):

Either check the return value.

```
if (send((void *) &pOutSig, sender((void *) &pSig) == -1)
{
     /*  whatever action is needed */
}
```

If you REALLY don't want to check the value, cast it to `void`.

```
(void)send((void *) &pOutSig, sender((void *) &pSig);
```

This tells the compiler to discard the return value.   It also tells other programmers - and coverity - that you are deliberately discarding the return value, rather than leaving the question open on whether you intended to.

If `TRACE_SEND_SIG()` is a macro, you'll need to modify it accordingly to do one of the above.

Comment: This trick can only avoid compiler warning. Coverity works on AST level and will still report it. It can only be either triaged as intentional or suppressed by code annotation /* coverity[check_return] */.